# Gmail OAuth API Count Messages PHP

Tags: php, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have the following code to count unread emails with Gmail OAuth API in PHP. The problem I have it will only return a max 100 due to API rate limits.  Is there anyway to count unread emails using oauth (not imap) and return correct value even if more than 100 items?

```
$optParams['labelIds'] = 'UNREAD'; 

            $messages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',$optParams);
   $list = $messages->getMessages();


    $result = count($list);
    echo "Total Inbox = ".$result ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an estimatedResultCount that's always returned on all list() calls but it's an estimate clearly.

If you want an exact count of total+unread messages on a label then you can now get that from label.get().

Comment: I need it to be accurate really rather than an estimate.  I want unread in just the inbox really. And was hoping to do total items in inbox also.

Comment: You're in luck.  Labels.get() should start returning this info early next week.  Keep an eye on:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/release-notes
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/get

Comment: Excellent.  Will look out for it. Thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

The way we were able to solve it is by creating a condition that if the number of unread emails exceeds 100 we simply put it in the following way "+100".